# Continuity of function between Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

The question is: Let B be a Banach space and let f from B into B be a linear map such that f^2=f and both Im(f) and Ker(f) are closed. We want to show that f is continuous.

So since Ker(f) is closed we can apply the 1st isomorphism theorem but how to use
the fact f is an idempotent here. I know without this assumption the conclusion
of the question is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As closed subspaces of the Banach space $B$, both $P := \operatorname{Im} f$ and $Q := \operatorname{Ker} f$ are themselves Banach spaces.

The map $a \colon P\times Q \to B;\; (p,q) \mapsto p+q$ is a bijection. (Why?) $a$ is continuous. (Why?)

The inverse of $a$ is

$$b \mapsto (f(b), b-f(b)),$$

therefore $f$ and $\operatorname{id}_B - f$ are continuous. (Why?)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Can you please explain a little bit about your last "why" above?

Comment: There's a _very_ important theorem about continuous surjective linear maps between Banach spaces.

Comment: I see, just apply Banach–Schauder theorem to function a we get the continuity of b and therefore f.

Comment: Yup, the open mapping theorem by whichever name.